# R:rpart: convertng the rpart fit object into a function

Tags: r, rpart

I can use rpart to predict (as below),

```
library(rpart)

datpred <-tail(car.test.frame,10)
fit <- rpart(Mileage ~ Weight+Price, car.test.frame)
predict(fit,newdata=datpred)
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE)
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
objects(fit)
```

Is there an easy way to convert the fit objects into a simple function that contains only the splitting logic on the data input and then outputs the prediction?

The reason for this is that I can then have the function within a single script with no need to load the fit objects from an external source.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A character vector is not a fit object. Why would you expect `predict` to work on a character vector? Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your object in a file using `dput()` then read it with `dget()`:

```
dput(fit, 'fit.dput')
rm(fit)
fit <- dget('fit.dput')
```

Answer (score 1):

The output that you are interested in, namely the variable names and the values at which the tree is split, are assembled by the `labels.rpart` function:

```
labels(fit)
#-----------
[1] "root"         "Weight>=2568" "Weight>=3088" "Weight< 3088"
[5] "Weight>=2748" "Weight< 2748" "Weight< 2568"
```

The 'splits' element of the fit object is where the cutpoints are stored (in the "index" column):

```
> fit$splits
       count ncat   improve  index adj
Weight    60    1 0.5953491 2567.5   0
Weight    45    1 0.5045118 3087.5   0
Weight    23    1 0.1476996 2747.5   0
```

You can look at the code but if you don't already know how to do that then this is not a function that is easy to understand:

```
> methods(labels)
[1] labels.default     labels.dendrogram* labels.dist*      
[4] labels.lm*         labels.rpart*      labels.survreg    
[7] labels.terms*     
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
> getAnywhere(labels.rpart)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation